# How can a user use logic (AND/OR) to filter a dashboard in tableau?

Tags: logic, tableau-api, dashboard

My client is looking for a way to filter a dashboard based on logic. We have 20+ products we sell and we want to be able to find customers that have purchased product A AND/OR Product B but not Product C. My data looks like this:

```
ID  |Beer   |Soda   |Chips
--------------------------
123 |0      |0      |1
234 |0      |1      |0
345 |0      |1      |1
456 |1      |1      |1
```

So let's say that my client wants to show how many customers purchased (Soda OR Chips) AND not beer. In the data above, 3 results would show. Of course they would want ALL scenarios possible, not JUST this one. This is only an example.

Comment: what is the question?

Comment: My question is how can I provide a way in my dashboard that will allow a user to filter based on AND and OR logic like the one I mentioned above?

Answer (score 0):

Pivot your data like this and use Product on the filter shelf. Tableau works best with tall data, not wide.

[image]